# Mirror the live HTTP requests on another server from tail'ed apache access log to confirm it can handle the load

Tags: apache-2.4, http, load-testing

I have an apache HTTP server, which is in production use. I have installed another server, which should do the same as this server, but I would like to do some simple load testing. The apache http server is stateless, and statically serves up many simple HTTP GET requests. I can see all the requests live with `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log`.

Is there a programme which will take this `tail`'ed output from an apache log, and as soon as it sees a GET request, send a similar GET request to this other server, and reporting roughly how many also get a 200.

This is a simple way to mirror the live traffic from another server, and confirms that the new server is able to handle the real load.

Comment: why don't you just benchmark both with a tool such as "apache benchmark" or "httpperf"?

Comment: `ab` can only work with a single URL, whereas I want to check the many different URLs that are coming in live (both web servers have a local cache, so ab would just test that cach)

Comment: what does it matter, you have only one set of workers for the whole server, they are not spread or work differently for the different virtualhosts, direct ab to the most costly request and benchmark it.

Answer (score 3):

The most user-friendly applicaton which can replay Apache HTTPD access log is probably [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

It comes with [Access Log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) sampler which generates HTTP requests from the access log file so you will be able to precisely replay the requests.

References:

- [Access log sampler Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf)
- [The JMeter Access Log Sampler - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-access-log-sampler-a-guide)